# Is it possible to change the color of the labels in fmsb radarchart?

Tags: r, radar-chart

The [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fmsb/fmsb.pdf) (pdf) doesn't seem to indicate any parameter responsible to change the labels' color. To be clear, I'm not referring to the numbers on the axis, but to the labels at the edges of the polygon.

I've used the first example taken from the solution given to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51766762/is-it-possible-to-draw-a-radar-chart-in-r-where-each-circle-has-a-different-colo) question.

I tried:

```
par(col.lab="grey")
```

before or after calling radarchart function, but it didn't work. The labels remained black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to insert the following snippet just before calling the `radarchart()` function:

```
par(col="grey")
```

Doing so one changes the specification for the default plotting color.
See [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.5.2/topics/par) for more.